# ref vs depends-on attributes in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am confused between ref and depends-on attribute in Spring.I read the spring doc but I am still confused.I wish to know the exact difference between the two and in which case which one shall be used.

Answer (score 13):

From the official documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html

> Beans on which the current bean depends. Any beans specified are guaranteed to be created by the container before this bean. Used infrequently in cases where a bean does not explicitly depend on another through properties or constructor arguments, but rather depends on the side effects of another bean's initialisation.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps an example of a situation where depends-on is needed would help. I use Spring to load and wire my beans. Here is an example bean definition:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="my.package.Class">
    <property name="destination" value="bean:otherBeanId?method=doSomething"/>
</bean>

<bean id="otherBeanId" class="my.package.OtherClass"/>
```

Notice that the property value is a string, which references *otherBeanId*. Because of the way this variable is resolved, Spring doesn't learn of the dependency, so it may destroy *otherBeanId* then *myBean*. This may leave *myBean* in a broken state for a little while.

I can use depends on to fix this problem as follows:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="my.package.Class" depends-on="otherBeanId">
    <property name="destination" value="bean:otherBeanId?method=doSomething"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a situation where a bean might be a property in another bean i.e; the property bean is directly involved in the bean definition as a property in such case we refer the beans with `ref` attribute.

There might be a situation where in a bean instantiation is required for the other bean to be successfully created, the other bean is not a property of the bean under definition, in such case we make use of the `depends-on` attribute.